# Simplifiy module use

Tags: python

I have a set of modules under one package food:

```
food:
    chocolate 
    sweets
    apples
    tuna
```

When I uses these classes in one client class, I have to make multiple importations to use the functions in each class.

So i would need

```
from chocolate import chocolate
from sweets import sweets 
from apples import apples
from tune import tuna
```

But i would like a single importation for all of these so:

```
from food import *
```

so I can have

```
choc = chocolate()
choc.eat
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's a facade pattern?

Comment: Did you mean `choc = chocolate.chocolate()`?

Comment: Do your modules really only contain one class each? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Wildcard imports (from  import *) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools.

Comment: fine, but any suggestions for simplifiying?